# Get GPS coordinates of location

Tags: api, google-maps, google-api, google-web-designer

[image: screenshot of a GoogleMaps frame]
I have tried out Google API for maps in my project. Now I need to fetch GPS coordinates of location selected by user for storing it in Mysql.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKeyQ&libraries=places"></script>
<title>Demo Maps</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe
width="600"
height="450"
frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=myKey
&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you could use the navigator.geolocation   features

```
  <script>
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            window.alert( "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        window.alert( "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
    }

    getLocation();
  </script>
```

Comment: This is for finding out current location.

Comment: I want coordinates of location selected by user;

Comment: how the user select  a coordinate  ?? ... by clicking ?? .i can not imagine what your users do  ...explain clearly  ...your need   ..( the GPS select by user  have no sense .. the GPS is inside your device)